# Could not set field value [49] value by reflection

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Could someone help me with the issue, I am having with Spring Boot 1.5.2 based project?

I have Parent and Categories entities
Parent, the straightforward one, has:

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "parent_id")
    private Long id;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE,
            org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE,
            org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.MERGE,
            org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.PERSIST,
            org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN})
    private List<Category> categories;

    public List<Category> getCategories() {
        return categories;
    }

    public void setCategories(List<Category> categories) {
        this.categories = categories;
    }
...setters, getters, etc
}
```

Categories table has a composite key (parent_id, category_code)
So I defined an Embeddable class

```
@Embeddable
public class CategoryKey implements Serializable {
    private String categoryCode;

    private Long parentId;

    ... getters, setters, overriden equals and hashCode method
}
```

In the Category entity I have

```
public class Category implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    private CategoryKey categoryKey;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("parentId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Parent parent;

    ... getters, setters,no-arg constructor
}
```

When I try issue a POST operation to save a new Parent, it throws

**Could not set field value [here is the new parent_id] value by reflection**

How to overcome this issue?

Comment: Any news on this? I'm having the exact same problem

Comment: What's your problem exactly? Could you post the code? I have redone the code and removed composite key.

Comment: hi nomadus! I manage to solve the problem. Sadly, I don't remember exactly how, but it was related to Mapping in both classes. Was after a lot of trial and error

Answer (score 0):

use String instead of long

`private Long id;` ===> `private String id;`